# Angularjs chat with strange polling

Tags: angularjs

I created a simple chat with the frontend in angularjs. It has on the left size a simple index, of all the conversations that user has, with a `show(chat_id)` action, that opens up on the right side the chat itself, using polling to fetch new messages.

The main piece of the controller that does the functionality described:

```
$scope.show = function(id) {
  $scope.chat = [];
  $scope.currentConversation = id;
  var poll = function(){
    conversation.get(id).then( function( conversation ) {
      $scope.chat = conversation.data.messages;
      $scope.form = true;
      $timeout(function() {poll()}, 5000)
    });
  }
  poll(); 
}
```

My problem, is whenever I click on two different conversations quickly, say `show(1)` and `show(2)` I get a weird behavior where it switches from conversation 1 to 2, back and forth, with the polling action.

Here is the get requests angular is making.
[image]

and for contextualization, here's the chat simple UI
[image]

Comment: What is `$timeout(function() {poll()}, 5000)` supposed to do? It calls poll() without any argument. Is it your real code? If not, then do post your real code.

Comment: Yup it's the real code. It is supposed to, every 5 seconds, get from the database all the messages, in case there's a new message.

Comment: But poll() expects an argument. And you don't pass any. And even if you passed one, this code, once you call show(1), refreshes the chat with the every 5 seconds. Call show(2), and it adds **another** recursive refresh, that doesn't replace the previous one.

Comment: Oh, I mistakenly left the argument of poll there, I corrected on question, but the same behavior happens

Comment: Now the last line calls the function with an argument it doesn't expect. Modify your code until it makes sense and reproduces the problem, then copy and paste that **real** code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comment, every time show() is called, you start a new recursive loop that polls the conversation with the given id every 5 seconds.

So, if you click 4 conversations (1, 2, 3 and 4), you will end up with a refresh of conversation 1 every 5 seconds, another refresh of conversation 2 every 5 seconds, etc.

That's not what you want. Once you show a conversation, you only want to refresh *that* conversation, not the other ones.

So you could use that following code that cancels the previous timeout every time show() is called, and that verifies that the displayed conversation ID is the right one when getting a response:

```
var timer;
$scope.show = function(id) {
  $scope.chat = [];
  $scope.currentConversation = id;
  if (timer) {
    $timeout.cancel(timer);
  }
  var poll = function(){
    conversation.get(id).then( function( conversation ) {
      if ($scope.currentConversation == id) {
        $scope.chat = conversation.data.messages;
        $scope.form = true;
        timer = $timeout(function() {poll()}, 5000);
      }
    });
  }
  poll(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do a check inside your inner function to make sure that `$scope.currentConversation === id`. That'll prevent it from losing context. My guess is that it's a race condition that you're clicking before the first
`conversation.get(id)` comes back.

```
$scope.show = function(id) {
  $scope.chat = [];
  $scope.currentConversation = id;
  var poll = function(){
    conversation.get(id).then( function( conversation ) {
      if ($scope.currentConversation !== id) return; // Prevent the race condition
      $scope.chat = conversation.data.messages;
      $scope.form = true;
      $timeout(function() {poll()}, 5000)
    });
  }
  poll(); 
}
```